# How to overwright laravel main config(site name for example) from setting table DB

Tags: laravel, config

I am creating a laravel cms and need to make site name dynamic in app.php
My question is how to overwrite any main config parameters like site name email configuration and also db with DB values?

Comment: You can check in .env file

Comment: You can do the queries at **AppServiceProvider** and write the configs - `config(['key' => 'value']);`.

Comment: How are you rendering your views? Is it with blade?

Comment: sougata-bose Thanks you so much,

Answer (score 0):

All Laravel configuration is in config folder but you can overwrite all values in `.env` file

You can find more information in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please read my question before leaving this comment, I am writing my own cms of course I know how env file works. I asked about how to make main laravel configuratin dynamic...